# Predefined model value and ng-options later binding

Tags: angularjs

I have the issue with Angular.js v1.3.11 and ng-options directive. The problem is next. I have a model value I know ahead but data for binding of options comes in AJAX request later and Angular.js produces that as two selected options: with my value and first one.

Html

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <select ng-model="selectedYear" ng-options="o.year as o.year for o in options"></select>
  </body>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.selectedYear = 2013;
    $scope.options = [];

    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.options = [{year: 2012}, {year: 2013}, {year: 2014}];
    });
});
```

Output

```
<select ng-model="selectedYear" ng-options="o.year as o.year for o in options" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
   <option value="0" selected="selected" label="2012">2012</option>
   <option value="1" selected="selected" label="2013">2013</option>
   <option value="2" label="2014">2014</option>
</select>
```

Plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/gFZ8Z7T5DhDPvk4G9tEU?p=preview

Comment: You really haven't defined your problem well and plunker demo seems to work. What are we supposed to see in demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug in 1.3 that no longer exists in 1.4. More information can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11727).

Answer (score 1):

If you use "track by" then you can leave the $scope.selectedYear outside the $timeout callback function. You shouldn't really worry about the selected attribute. Change your code to include "track by o.year" and remove the "select as" part:

```
<select ng-model="selectedYear" ng-options="o.year for o in options track by o.year"></select>
```

Also in your controller you can set the predefined selectedYear like below to the object.

```
$scope.selectedYear = {year: 2013};
```

Here is a working plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/UMfEIWlBwBnyj9wQ1FEx?p=preview

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't a recommended way according to official documentation:

Do not use select as and track by in the same expression. They are not designed to work together.

https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.13/docs/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: Sorry wasn't aware of that. Will edit my answer with a working example with "track by" and without using "select as".

Comment: Thanks for the solution but it means I need to wrap every value that follows this pattern into an object. I'd prefer not to over-complicate the logic using selected scalar values just to make it works from Angular's point. Anyway, good work and if there aren't other options would be accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing this same issue.  I used your plunker and updated the bits to 1.4 RC2.  Be careful because this is a Release Candidate and is a pre-release.

Here is the working plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/UVL3dxYy0PNRcXuXG5y0?p=preview

```
<script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.0-rc.2"></script>
```